# How to add row break in reportviewer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008, reportviewer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAVKO.png)
I have a reportviewer , how to generate empty lines as shown in the picture. help me

i tried setting show in visibility but when in case of data more than 1 page the 2nd page doesn't have row blank

Comment: Hi. It is much better for us, when code is shared as text not as image